# Sending WooCommerce order to NetSuite

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm attempting to take an order from WooCommerce using the Rest API, and add that information into NetSuite as a Sales Order. I can successfully grab the order information from WooCommerce, but I am unsuccessful when adding the order into NetSuite using the PHPToolkit. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

/*
 * Add a customer to Netsuite.
 * 
 * paramtypesmap
 *  
 */

require_once 'includes/functions.php';

// create array of fields
$itemArr = array();
$i = 0;
$service = new NetSuiteService();

$salesOrder = new SalesOrder();

$salesOrder->entity = new RecordRef();
$salesOrder->entity->internalId = 512;
$salesOrder->entity->type = 'customer';

$salesOrder->shipDate = formatDate('2014-10-06T07:12:57.000-07:00');

$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 1000);

$siteCategory = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$siteCategory->operator = "anyOf";
$siteCategory->searchValue = array('internalId' => 512);

$search = new ItemSearchBasic();
$search->internalId = $siteCategory;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;

$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
$products = $searchResponse->searchResult->recordList->record; 


$salesOrder->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$item = new SalesOrderItem();
$item->item = new RecordRef();
$item->item->internalId = 531;
$item->quantity = 1;
//removeEmpty($item->item);
//removeEmpty($item);

$item->price = new RecordRef();
$item->price->internalId = 1;
$item->amount = 55.3;


$salesOrder->itemList->item=array(0=>$item);


//Equivalent too print_r
pr($item);

//Equivalent too print_r
pr($salesOrder);

removeEmpty($salesOrder);

$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record  = $salesOrder;

//$service->setFields($purchaseOrderFields);

$response = $service->add($request);
if (!$response->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo getErrors($response->writeResponse);
} else {
    echo success($response->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId);
}
?>
```

I'm just trying to work from the ground up to see what fields are required and how to build them, however I keep getting this error when ran:

```
Please choose a child matrix item
```

I have spent the last couple of days attempting to try some Google Fu on the problem, but with my luck found nothing. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the error message, you are trying to submit a Parent Matrix Item instead of the child. Verify it by checking the Item Record with internal id 531.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve correct internal ids is to import Matrix Items directly from NetSuite into WooCommerce as variable products. Assigning the internal id to each variation.